# How to put loading image when something is processing?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having page in that when we click on create button its sends web request to get the all links but mean while it takes some time to get all links working or not so at that time I want to put image load

```
 Button ID="btnRender" runat="server" Text="Page Render" OnClick="btnRender_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn_submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="javascript:finda();" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn_createlink" runat="server" Text="Create link" OnClick="btn_createlink_Click" />
```

i want to call on btn_createlink_Click" button when user clicks the image or text should appear

Comment: What kind of web request are you doing? Ajax?

Comment: httpwebrequest for getting links

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Without Ajax Tool:**

 This will call the loading image on button click and hide the image on page load completes.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function ShowProgressBar() {
        document.getElementById('dvProgressBar').style.visibility = 'visible';
      }

      function HideProgressBar() {
        document.getElementById('dvProgressBar').style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:HideProgressBar()" >
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>
  <div style="float:left;">
      <asp:Button ID="btn_createlink" runat="server" Text="Create link" OnClick="btn_createlink_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:ShowProgressBar()" />
  </div>
  <div ID="dvProgressBar" style="float:left;visibility: hidden;" >
        <img src="/images/progress_bar.gif" /> resolving address, please wait...
  </div>
  <br style="clear:both" />
</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are right but <asp:Button ID="btn_createlink" runat="server" Text="Create link" OnClick="btn_createlink_Click" /> i want to call that image on this button

Comment: I found a lot of solutions, only your solution easily and workable, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this happen with the help of Multithreading with the BackgroundWorker Component. 
Have a look on [Multithreading with Backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ywkkz4s1.aspx)

[Backgroundworker](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker)
[C# backgroundworker](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker)

[and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851069/background-worker-thread-problem)

You can call your loading.gif image in _Dowork method. Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry bro its like (http://validator.w3.org/checklink) so when user will click on check its takes some time right to check links at that time i want that loading image

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

You might want to have a look at HttpResponse.Flush

> Forces all currently buffered output to be sent to the client. The Flush method can be called multiple times during request processing.

See the following link: [HttpResponse.Flush Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.flush.aspx)

You could show a loading image and call this method every X number of loaded links.

**OLD:**

Since the question is missing information, I will assume that you are doing an Ajax call in order to get a collection of links from the server and update a table.

I would suggest you to use jQuery and follow this previous answer on SO in order to display an animated loading spinner when a request is made and hide it when it is completed.

See the link: [Jquery Ajax Loading image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8761756/1036025)

Comment: sorry bro its like (http://validator.w3.org/checklink)  so when user will click on check its takes some time right to check links at that time i want that loading image.but its not ajax

Comment: @hitarth I edited my answer according to your comment. I suggest to use the HttpResponse.Flush method.